# How can I get products insights from facebook using the api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-ads-api

I have uploaded a feed in my dynamic ad on facebook and I would need the 
insights(ctr,clicks,impressions,conversions) for every product(not per campaign or
ad level). I saw there is api for campaign and ad level but I need per product level. 
I would need something like this(Product 1: clicks=22, ctr=12, conversions=2 and so on). So I can select the first 25% that have higher ctr and run them in front (or set bid if it is possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For getting all products of a dynamic ad, you need to use `&breakdowns=product_id` on your insights API Call for example:

```
/{campaign_id}/insights?fields=clicks,ad_id,adset_id,campaign_id,account_id,impressions,cpc,cost_per_inline_link_click,cost_per_inline_post_engagement,cpm,ctr,inline_link_click_ctr&level=ad&breakdowns=product_id
```

be aware, that this might mean a huge amount of data so maybe you have to use an [Async Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/asyncrequests/v2.10).

Comment: Greeat, it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: then please mark this question as solved. Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer